# How to get nearby places from Google SDK using iOS and Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How I can get nearby location from Google SDK in iOS and Swift? I need all nearby places without any type and category?

Client don't want use this url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=lat,long&radius=1000&sensor=true&key=key

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with this API call: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.226531,4.190688&destinations=51.114476,4.139618|51.148123,4.182590

There are three parameters in this URL,

JSON is used to return the response

origins contain the long and lat of the current location of the user and

destination contains all the addresses form which you want to find the nearest distance. the addresses will be in long and lat format and are separated by "|".

The response will be as follow

```
    {
  "destination_addresses" : [
  "Dorpstraat 70, 9140 Temse, België",
  "Eigenlostraat 38, 9100 Sint-Niklaas, België"

],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Provinciale Baan 37, 9120 Beveren, België" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "16,3 km",


 "value" : 16346
       },
       "duration" : {
          "text" : "22 min.",
          "value" : 1321


 },
   "status" : "OK"
    },
    {
       "distance" : {
      "text" : "10,5 km",
      "value" : 10521
   },
   "duration" : {
      "text" : "17 min.",


       "value" : 1003
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK" 
}
```

All you have to do is to get the nearest destination on the time basis .

Cheers